# Get string of corresponding placeholder according to format string

Tags: java, string, format

How can I get strings of corresponding placeholder according to format string？

For example:

The format string is `My name is %s, and I'm %d years old`, and I have a string `My name is Mike, and I'm 18 years old`。How to get `Mike` and `18` according to the format string, which correspond to placeholder `%s` and `%d` separately？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a *regular expression* with two groups. One to match any non-whitespace after `My name is`  ending with a comma, the other to match any consecutive digits after `I'm` and ending in `years old`. Like,

```
String str = "My name is Mike, and I'm 18 years old";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("My name is (\\S+), and I'm (\\d+) years old");
Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
if (m.find()) {
    System.out.printf("name=%s,age=%d%n", m.group(1), 
            Integer.parseInt(m.group(2)));
}
```

Which outputs

```
name=Mike,age=18
```